# cURL error 7: Failed to connect to maps.googleapis.com port 443

Tags: laravel, google-maps, guzzle

I got following Error when get Distance between two places in Laravel. i use guzzlehttp/guzzle package to get Google Map api response. i previously declare use GuzzleHttp\Client; How to solve this Issue.

> Error : cURL error 7: Failed to connect to maps.googleapis.com port
>   443: Network is unreachable (see
>   http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

```
$pickupaddress = urlencode($frmplace);
$deliveryaddress = urlencode($destplace);
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$disrequest = $client->get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins='.$pickupaddress.'&destinations='.$deliveryaddress.'&mode=driving&key=ASESdsfsdfsdfdsfdf')->getBody();

$disjsondecode = json_decode($disrequest);
$tripdistance = $disjsondecode->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->text;
```

Comment: Have you tried doing POST instead of GET, with cURL you have to do POST to get google maps api response.

Comment: Can you double check if you are using valid certificates with SSL connection? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67842936

Comment: can you verify your opened ports ? _> https://superuser.com/questions/529830/get-a-list-of-open-ports-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

CURL ERROR NO 7 Issue occur in two cases : 
1. Your server blocked port for security reasons. so you can ask to your server provider to enable it and server provider enabled to you.
2. Api provider does not accept different domain or some security or protected.

In your case Google disabled the service or pass credentials.

also use javascript library or google sdk.